# Google Cloud Spanner Session not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have an error when i call my spanner dev instance after 1 or 2 hours. Without a call.

```
Error: Session not found: xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx
```

I have current spanner node.js client installed and the newest grpc package. Is it required to hold the connection open with a keep alive call?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using google cloud spanner library or you define your own library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloudspanner sessions can automatically be closed by Google if being idle for a while: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/sessions#keep_an_idle_session_alive

Doing a simple keep alive query like SELECT 1 every now and then is all you need.